# Apply borders in many cells openpyxl

Tags: border, apply, openpyxl

I'm new, I want to know if you can help me I do not understand how to select multiple cells with openpyxl and apply a border,if you could please give me an example.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

property is called border (not borders)

Try this:

```
     def set_border(ws, cell_range):
    rows = list(ws.iter_rows(cell_range))
    side = Side(border_style='thin', color="FF000000")

    rows = list(rows)  # we convert iterator to list for simplicity, but it's not memory efficient solution
    max_y = len(rows) - 1  # index of the last row
    for pos_y, cells in enumerate(rows):
        max_x = len(cells) - 1  # index of the last cell
        for pos_x, cell in enumerate(cells):
            border = Border(
                left=cell.border.left,
                right=cell.border.right,
                top=cell.border.top,
                bottom=cell.border.bottom
            )
            if pos_x == 0:
                border.left = side
            if pos_x == max_x:
                border.right = side
            if pos_y == 0:
                border.top = side
            if pos_y == max_y:
                border.bottom = side

            # set new border only if it's one of the edge cells
            if pos_x == 0 or pos_x == max_x or pos_y == 0 or pos_y == max_y:
                cell.border = border
```

Comment: the code compiles without errors, but I see no border

Answer (score 1):

Now you can iterate directly in the worksheet. I adapted the code

```py
def set_border(ws, cell_range):
    rows = list(ws[cell_range])
    side = Side(border_style='thin', color="FF000000")

    rows = list(rows)  # we convert iterator to list for simplicity, but it's not memory efficient solution
    max_y = len(rows) - 1  # index of the last row
    for pos_y, cells in enumerate(rows):
        max_x = len(cells) - 1  # index of the last cell
        for pos_x, cell in enumerate(cells):
            border = Border(
                left=cell.border.left,
                right=cell.border.right,
                top=cell.border.top,
                bottom=cell.border.bottom
            )
            if pos_x == 0:
                border.left = side
            if pos_x == max_x:
               border.right = side
            if pos_y == 0:
               border.top = side
            if pos_y == max_y:
               border.bottom = side

            # set new border only if it's one of the edge cells
            if pos_x == 0 or pos_x == max_x or pos_y == 0 or pos_y == max_y:
               cell.border = border
```

And just call it like that:

```py
set_border(ws, 'A16:I17')
```